# Ninepatch inconsistent for arrow button

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: Nine-patch image]

[image: Image after rendering]

The problem with rendered images is that the left side triangle isn't smooth enough. There is a bit of jagged edge on the slopes. This was found in the draw9patch tool's preview too, but couldn't tackle it so far.

Any hint regarding solution will appreciated.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

Comment: Sorry,I do respect android norms and standard, but this is clients requirement and I have to live with it.

Comment: Right, been there, seen that :( Anyways, the ninepatch format is not really useful for images with diagonal lines, like arrows, as the specified stretch-area will cause those lines to look broken. If you have to use a ninepatch, you'll have to mark the entire left side as stretchable to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you specify too wide area for the height shrink/stretch. Put just one black pixel in the leftmost pixel column (it's tricky where to put it, actually. I'd put one pixel in the very top of your image and one more - in the very bottom).

Comment: I had tried that too, but in result I got those jagged edges relocated to corners.

Comment: You need to put these two pixels outside your actual image - to allow android to shrink/stretch transparent regions only. So, consequently, you need to add two lines of transparent pixels to the top and the bottom of your image.

Comment: U mean add an extra transparent pixel area on both sides in actual image?

Comment: Exactly, and put the black pixels at the left of these two lines.

Comment: Great, I'll accept this as an answer. Hope you edit ur response :) so that others get clear idea.